# Passing connected ble peripheral using segue in swift 4?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to pass my connected ble peripheral as an object to the next view controller scene but it works for two views and then I keep losing the reference to the peripheral object? 
Can someone guide me the correct way to pass peripheral as an object from one view controller class to another?

//From BLECentral class to my First View Controller class

```
peripheral.discoverServices([BLEService_UUID])
```

//Once connected, move to new view controller to manager incoming and outgoing data

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


        let firstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController


        firstViewController.peripheral = peripheral


        navigationController?.pushViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
```

//First and Second views are connected using a Modal segue with segue identifier "Second_View"
//From First View to Second View

```
//First View Class
viewDidLoad(){
peripheral.discoverServices([BLEService_UUID])
}

//Under button click action

@IBAction bla bla bla(){
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second_View", sender: self)
}

//I want to override the performSegue before its called

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
  if (segue.identifier == "Second_View") {
   
  let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

  secondViewController?.peripheral = bleperipheral
  }
}
```

//Where bleperipheral is coming from BLE Central class

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {


        blePeripheral = peripheral

        self.peripherals.append(peripheral)

        self.RSSIs.append(RSSI)

        peripheral.delegate = self

        self.baseTableView.reloadData()

        if blePeripheral == nil {

            print("Found new pheripheral devices with services")

            print("Peripheral name: \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")

            print("**********************************")

            print ("Advertisement Data : \(advertisementData)")

        }

    }
```

And the BLEService_UUID is declared as per my ble string in UUID.swift class
I Can writeValue and readValue from peripheral but can someone guide me a more stable approach in passing the peripheral object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need this object throughout the app (i.e. as a data service) you might want to consider creating a service class that holds this peripheral. Using the singleton pattern it is possible just have to keep in mind that singletons stay in memory until your app exits. If this object is meant to be cleared at some point then singleton might not be your best bet, but if you're planning on keeping it anyway, then go like this:

```
class BTService{
  static let instance = BTService()
  //set up your peripheral here you can have a setup function that you call early in your app}
```

The setup funciton you can call in the first viewDidLoad or even in applicationFInishedLaunching in appDelegate. Then on any viewcontroller you refer to this peripheral as `BTService.instance.peripheral` or whatever you call it, also the setup function you can access through the instance.setupBT.

Comment: Hi Andras M, thanks for your response. Can you please tell me How to setup my peripheral in the BTService class? I'm currently using the Adafriuit basic chat code as reference to connect and communicate with ble. https://github.com/adafruit/Basic-Chat.git Please tell me what bit of code I need to put in the BTService swift class according to the above reference link? Thanks

Comment: Can I use this singleton block? https://github.com/gauravkg15/Drag-N-Drop-BLE.git

Comment: Hi! You can use this. You just have to always call it's functions to get the list ofvisible BT devices and also to connect to them etc. But it's a great starting point. Not sure if you're building an app for release or just experimenting with one device (in which case you can hardcode things.